# need to get result of a Invoke-sshCommand to a variable

Tags: powershell, ssh

I am trying to get the results of command to return as a variable using power shell on  windows 10 connecting to a fortigate firewall.

```
$ip = "192.168.38.1"
New-SshSession $ip -port 2222 -username xxxxxx -password xxxxxx
$dhcp = Invoke-SshCommand $ip -command 'config system console
set output standard
end
config system dhcp server
show'
    
$dhcp | select-object output
```

i have also tried with the invoke-sshcommand using this method

```
$dhcp = (Invoke-SshCommand $ip -command 'config system console
set output standard
end
config system dhcp server
show').Output
```

both ways do not put the output into the variable

any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code to connect to a Linux server via SSH, run the command `ls` to list the contents of the directory to the variable `$output` and then print that to the screen to confirm it has a value

```
$ip = "192.168.38.1"
$username = "MyUserName"
$password = "MyPass"
$securePass = ConvertTo-SecureString $password  -AsPlainText -Force

[pscredential]$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($username, $securePass)

$ssh = New-SSHSession -Computername $ip -Credential $cred -AcceptKey
$output = Invoke-SshCommand -Command "ls" -SSHSession $ssh
    
$output

Remove-SSHSession $ssh | Out-Null
```

It looks like perhaps you have not specified the `-SSHSession` parameter for your call to `Invoke-SshCommand`

Comment: the -sshsession parameter does not seem to exist "Invoke-SshCommand : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'SSHSession'."

Comment: What version does Get-command Invoke-SSHCommand  return?

Comment: it is showing 2.1.3

Comment: @RobertAllen what happens if you try updating to the latest version  -`Install-Module -Name Posh-SSH  -RequiredVersion 3.0.8 -AllowClobber`